# Why $_GET stills get the last folder that's indicated on my RewriteBase directive

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm doing a simple MVC from scratch and my project is in `/var/www/test_mvc` where I have two subfolders: `app` and `public`. the public subfolder is where the users will access.

So, in my .htaccess I have this code:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /test_mvc/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In the constructor of the Index controller I print the values fro `$_GET["url"]` and if I request `localhost/test_mvc/public/index/greet/name` the value that shows is `/public/index/greet/name`

How can I solve it to get the value `index/greet/name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test_mvc/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But I would like to know why my RewriteBase includes the public folder on the url value.

Comment: `RewriteBase` only works on target URL not for the matching